# "No Java runtime present, requesting install" for Ghidra Installation

Tags: java, security, ghidra

Trying to run Ghidra, which require me to download Java runtime and development kit (JDK) and put it on the path. I extracted the JDK and got the bin.

However, I'm not really sure how to do the following steps:

> 1. Open ~/.bashrc with an editor of your choice. For example: vi ~/.bashrc

Do I need to download vim for this? I tried inputting this in homebrew and got nothing but a INSERT at the bottom. And when I type step 2 in it it didn't work as well.

> 2. At the very end of the file, add the JDK bin directory to the PATH variable:
>    export PATH=/bin:$PATH

I'm using a Macbook and it would be appreciated if someone can guide me through the process! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After a typical installation of Java/JDK it should already be on the path.
You can verify this by opening the Terminal app and typing in `java -version`.

If you did a non-standard installation I suggest using homebrew to install the JDK.
Then there should be no reason to update your `~/.bashrc` file.

As regards to the editor - use whatever you like.
If you know how to use `vim`, you can definitely try it - it should be preinstalled on macOS (just type `vim` in the Terminal).